# Relative Extrema using Lagrange Multipliers - is it correct?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, extreme-value-analysis

Here is the problem:

> Find an extrema of $f(x,y)=y^2+x$ with the given condition
> $x^2+2y^2=1$.

I solved it this way:
$L(x,y,\phi)=y^2+x+\lambda(x^2+2y^2-1)$
$\frac{\delta L}{\delta x}=1+2\lambda x =0$
$\frac{\delta L}{\delta y}=2y+4\lambda y =2y(1+2\lambda)=0$
$\frac{\delta L}{\delta \phi}=x^2+2y^2-1 =0$
$=>$
$x=\frac{-1}{2\lambda};\quad y=0;\quad\lambda=\pm\frac{1}{2};\quad= >\quad x=\pm1$.
After that I took the second derivative from $L$ and got this:
$P_1 =(1,0)$ when $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}$ – is the relative maximum ($L''<0$), $f(x,y)=1$, and
$P_2 =(-1,0)$ when $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ – is the relative minimum ($L''>0$), $f(x,y)=-1$.

I wanted to check myself with the given solutions, and here what it says:

> **The solution:**
> $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+x, x\in[-1,1]$,
> $(1,0)$ – the maximum, $f(1,0)=1$,
> $(-1,0)$ – the minimum, $f(-1,0)=-1$.

And my question is – why it says the solution is the function with only one $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}$ value? I can't get it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question, since that solution doesn't mention $\lambda$ at all.

Comment: It does mention it, not explicitly. The function in the solution $f(x,y)$ is the $L$-function with $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}$ applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation gives $x=-\frac{1}{2\lambda}$ as you say. This division is justified because when $\lambda=0$ you get an inconsistent equation. (Mathematically this is because this function has no critical points.)

But the second equation can be satisfied two ways: *either* $y=0$ *or* $\lambda=-1/2$. The latter gives you a value of $x$ from the first equation and then you can use the constraint to get corresponding value(s) of $y$. For the former you can just go directly to the constraint to get the corresponding value(s) of $x$, because the first equation is just going to get you a value of $\lambda$ which you do not really need.

That said, the solution you're showing isn't using Lagrange multipliers, it is just using direct substitution of the constraint to replace $y^2$ in the objective function, and then using the constraint to restrict $x$ to be within an interval.

Comment: I think I see, it's possible to get $x=-1$ from the last equation when we know that $y=0$ and we left with $x^2=1$ (and we don't need the second $\lambda$-value).
But I didn't understand what do mean talking about restricting $x$ to be within an interval? How it can help?

Comment: @KitKolouv Their method is just doing global optimization on $1/2-x^2+x$ for $x \in [-1,1]$, which follows from replacing $y^2$ by $(1-x^2)/2$ from the constraint and then realizing that the constraint also restricts $x \in [-1,1]$. The interval is why $x=-1$ is the location of the minimum even though $1/2-x^2/2+x$ is unbounded below.